# How to hide the cursor in a C# console application on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, console, mono, cursor

I am writing a C# application which is running on Linux with Mono, and I want to hide the console cursor. But since this `Console.CursorVisible = false` seems to do nothing at all, is there another way of doing this, e.g. a console command or a native function?

Comment: If it doesn't work, time to file a bug with the Mono project. This works fine on WIndows; it calls the native `SetConsoleCursorInfo` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly dependent upon the terminal/shell type you are using, but on OS-X iTerm or Terminal bash here is how I do it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.Start("tput", "civis -- invisible");
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    Console.Read(); // no cursor
    Process.Start("tput", "cnorm -- normal");
    Console.Read(); // with cursor
}
```

This should work fine on Linux/bash and possibly others as it is using the `terminfo` database, if it does not, I would check your terminfo database for the missing elements.